# ssh, agent forwarding stops working after a few days ...

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, ssh-agent

I've been facing an interesting issue for a few weeks now.  Part of our fleet is only reachable via a jump-host.

In the past I had no issues w/ logging into the jump-host from my workstation using ssh -A and maintain a session for extended periods of time [yes, I know that's bad practice, not here for a lecture on a foul habit =}], and connect on from there to other machines w/o password entry as expected.

Now every so often going to my uxterm with the active session to the jump host gives me a

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

If I disconnect, and w/o restarting the agent connect to the jump host again, all works as before.

How do I diagnose what's going on there?

Extra information: my workstation is Ubuntu 16.04, the jump host is 14.04, recently upgraded from 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

When using agent forwarding, `ssh` actually forwards the UNIX socket to a directory in `/tmp` and the sets `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to point to it.

Effectively, thus means that only a new remote shell will inherit `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. Older sessions, will keep pointing to a socket that no longer exists. You could just `export` it again if you don't want to open a new shell

Comment: But why is the socket being torn down these days?  It used to work OK for years. :)

Comment: It's not so much that it gets torn down than it gets moved, when reconnecting the socket is placed in a random folder

Comment: Maybe I didn't quite explain myself well enough, I'm not reconnecting. I'm keeping a session to the jump host open, sometimes for weeks.  But in the last two months or so (since the upgrade to 14.04 of the jump host) I can't connect to other machines from the jump host anymore w/ "public key denied" after a couple of days.

Comment: What does `ssh-add -l` say when run on the jump host?

Comment: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: How bizarre ... this kind of implies that the session was torn down and re-established w/o me "losing" the session from the desktops perspective.

Comment: I guess at this point bug tracking would be trying to let a session live for a while with `ssh` in verbose mode, see what gives

Comment: fwiw, I too experience the same thing - long-lived ssh connections (e.g. months!) lose ability to access ssh agent on origin machine after a day or so.  I guess this is a very rare usage as few seem to experience this bug.  Only workaround is to create a new connection that inherits different ssh-agent env params.  Copying env vars from new working connection to old connection also works.